# I want to write a tool without usage entry barriers. Do I have to write it in C?

Tags: language-agnostic, open-source, portability

I want to write an open-source tool for use by developers. I want to eliminate entry barriers, so if they like the idea, they just get the tool and start playing with it.

In particular, I don't want an "Oh, should I also install 200Mb of ThatLanguage runtime libraries? Oh, so they don't build on my latest version of Linux?" entry barrier.

Should I write this tool in C, then? Or is Python, or Java, or whatever, already sufficiently widespread to not worry about this sort of things altogether (everyone already has them installed)?

Well, of course I know that they are freaking hugely widespread, but still - **are there any major benefits to writing a super-lightweight zero-dependency tool**, or am I being too much of a perfectionist?

Comment: What does the tool do? C has less in the way of standard (and hence portable) libraries than Python or Java, so might actually require *more* separate dependencies to be satisfied.

Comment: The tool is a special kind of logger - it shall have "client" bindings to multiple languages and a server, and it's the server that I'm asking about. I'll need only basic I/O and threading libraries; perhaps just something like epoll.

Comment: threading is not portable in C, neither is socket I/O, or named pipes, or any other form of inter-process I/O (unless you count files, I guess). So you'll either need compile-time conditionals in your app, to do the Windows thing on Windows and the POSIX thing in most other places, or you'll have to rely on non-standard compatibility libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write it first. If it is worth it people will use it.

Beyond that, (almost) everyone has Java, Python, and Ruby installed (especially devs). Some languages are still esoteric enough that it might not be worth it for 'that one app' (erlang, haskell, etc.).

Just write it though, that's the important part. From there it can be ported, rewritten, adopted, but none of that can happen if the tool isn't written first.

Comment: I agree with you that Java is widely spread. But Python and Ruby are not even close to that. But that may just be my own perspective.

Comment: I agree. I constantly see over-engineered solutions for projects that no one uses. If it is successful, all of these concerns can be addressed. If it is not, think of all the resources that were saved! This will not be the determining factor of success.

Answer (score 1):

It won't help if people don't know C.

If you write your own DSL, you can have people use that API and not worry about which language you choose.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about the core framework installed on the box already, not the knowledge to actually change the code.

Comment: I agree, but I'm saying that if s/he decides on C and users don't know it they're still hosed.  S/he has to abstract implementation language choice away from clients; once that's sorted s/he's free to choose whatever s/he wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Write it in whatever ***common*** language you like. Everybody has installed .NET framework or JVM. The only difference between your C approach and Java or C# is, that you would link additional libraries directly to your program (opposed to standard libraries). 
On the other hand I would hesitate to write it in some exotic language, for example smalltalk, because normal user does not know what is it squak or smalltalk itself and could be worried about installing the wierd thing :-).

I also think, that you should be concerned more about developers, because you write, you want it to be open source. I dont know anyone, who wants to write his own Swing, Spring or any other framework just to be independent of something. Also its (usually) much faster and easier to write it in JIT Language, than to code it in assembler...

Comment: "Everybody has installed .NET framework"—this isn't true.  .NET's only available for Windows, and you can't assume that people have Mono installed.

Comment: Yes thats true...lets change it...everybody has installed .NET Framework, or knows, what is it and how to install Mono :-) (I really dont think, that this is a barrier, if his library/tool is worth it :-))

Comment: Nope, I'm not installing Mono on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest what Reese suggested but take a slightly different approach: write it first, preferably in a language that allows you to quickly prototype and develop your program. Then, and this is the most important part, document the protocal you've developed.

I'm giving this advice because you mentioned that your "application" may later have bindings in lots of different languages and it is a client/server architecture. Well, two of the biggest applications in the world started out like this.

Bittorrent started out as Python code. This allowed very quick prototyping of the concept to get it working. The main thing that it had going for it was that the original code was well written and well documented. This later on allowed other people to port the protocol to other languages.

HTTP and HTML is an even bigger success story and started out with an even less popular language at the time it was written: objective-C. Even better than bittorrent, the protocol itself is very simple and very well documented. People didn't care that the original implementation was in a language that they've never seen before that uses square brackets in strange ways on a NeXT cube. The concept and execution was good and people quickly ported it to their favourite programming languages. Again, objective-C was chosen to aid in quick prototyping. Legend has it that the original implementation was written in just a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, you have to write it in C. If it were written in any language other than C (except perhaps C++ or Perl), I would definitely stop to consider whether the necessary build tools, runtime tools, and/or interpreter for that language would be available everywhere I might need the tool before getting myself dependent upon it. If the tool were meant for use in build scripts, I would consider it a complete show-stopper, since I can't expect anyone who wants to build my software to have random arbitrary language environments installed.

The reason I mentioned C++ and Perl as exceptions is that they're both largely portable in a formal sense. They have implementations that work without significant ties to the host implementation, and can be built not just on any current popular system but on any system that remotely adheres to standards. Python is quite the opposite, with strong dependencies on the underlying system's dynamic loader; I've been completely unable to get Python to work on various systems that only support static linking.

ocaml is another possible choice that has a very portable implementation, but it's not widely installed and people who aren't familiar with it tend to frown on it for no good reason.

Comment: What about Java? I'm not aware of a platform where the server-side part of my software would be useful, but Java would be absent or at least difficult to get :)

Comment: I don't think I've ever had a system with java installed. For a long time there was no free-software implementation at all. I suppose the situation is better now, but I don't think I'd even consider a tool written in java.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your program in C, then you will have the dependency of the platform (Windows != Linux != AIX, etc). If you are talking only about writing this tool for one OS, or rather THE OS (Linux;-), then I think that you can have a reasonable amount of confidence that your app will work on almost any system, especially if you use an Open Source language. If you want to run the app on Windows, I wouldn't count on any of those languages being installed on the host system. Your highest confidence across platforms will be with Java.

If possible you could use the lightest weight framework possible and put it online, where it can be viewed in a browser. What does your app do? Would it work as a web app?

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest go for Delphi. If you want to make it portable, you can do it since most of the Delphi code is kylix compatible.